# How can I prevent company-mode completing numbers?

Tags: completion, company-mode

In org-mode, when I type some numbers, company always pops up the number completion like:

> 20
>  20001   -----------1
> 200111 ----------2

These numbers come from my org-mode files.

I would like to turn off company number completion. How can I do this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This can be solved by modifying company-transformers with the following code:

```
(push (apply-partially #'cl-remove-if
                      (lambda (c)
                        (or (string-match-p "[^\x00-\x7F]+" c)
                            (string-match-p "[0-9]+" c)
                            (if (equal major-mode "org")
                                (>= (length c) 15)))))
             company-transformers)
```

With this code:

1. remove those non-ANSII candidates.
2. remove any completion containing numbers.
3. remove any candidate which is longer than 15 in org-mode.

All kinds of things can be customized.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Although this answer is good, I think sharing emacs snippets it's a lot easier if they just do one thing, and specifically the one thing asked for. I could probably remove all the code I don't need, but as someone who's not proficient in and doesn't care that much for elisp sharing a cleaner method recudes the complexity of my .emacs greatly

Answer (score 6):

This is probably coming from the dabbrev back end. You can remove it like this:

```
(delete 'company-dabbrev company-backends)
```

Answer (score -2):

You can set `company-dabbrev-other-buffers` to `nil`, so company only searches in the active buffer:

```el
(setq company-dabbrev-other-buffers nil)
```