# company-lsp invokes completion on numbers

Tags: company-mode

This is quite annoying, when I'm typing a number company invokes completion after I type a `.` or when the number of digits exceeds `company-minimum-prefix-length`.

This will trigger other company-backends like `company-dabbrev-code` or `company-yasnippet` (if you've it enabled) or `company-keyword`.

Is there anyway I can get company to avoid completion on numbers for all major-modes?

Comment: Why shouldn't there be completion after a number and a `.`? If I type `100.ti` in Ruby, I would hope to see some completions.

Comment: This seems to be valid only for Ruby. Is there any other language which allows this?

Comment: Not sure. Maybe not the other popular ones. But in OO languages, it's likely due to the problem with parsing the decimal sign.

Comment: Possibly, related: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/9835/how-can-i-prevent-company-mode-completing-numbers

Comment: @Mahdi that does not work. I tried that out before posting this question